# What evidence do we have for (and against) Unique Games Conjecture?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, unique-games-conjecture

[Subhash Khot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhash_Khot)'s [Unique Games Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_games_conjecture) is one of active research areas in complexity theory.

> What evidence do we have for it? What evidence do we have against it?

Comment: Could you provide some references, links, and what evidence you have for/against already?  Otherwise please make this biglist type question a community wiki.

Comment: I agree that it should be community wiki.

Comment: as phrased, it definitely should be CW.

Comment: Thanks to Daniel for the link to Khot's nice survey. (A relatively older related post on Computational Complexity blog: http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2010/03/unique-games-redux.html)

Comment: I proposed a better approximation algorithm for the vertex cover problem ([a 1.999999-approximation algorithm](https://vixra.org/abs/2107.0045) by solving a well-known SDP model and a randomized procedure). It is not published, yet. But, I am sure that it is true (I am grateful if anyone identify any potential issues). I think my paper is **an evidence against** the Unique Games Conjecture.

Comment: Please don't use the "Post Your Answer" button to submit content which does not attempt to answer the question at the top of this page. If you want to post a new question, there is a separate "Ask" button for that; but probably review the [help] first, and in particular [How to ask.](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Khot gave a UGC survey talk at CCC 2010. The write-up is [here](http://cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/UGCSurvey.pdf). The final segment (bottom of page 30) has his opinions on this question.

Answer (score 10):

Another interesting survey about UGC by Khot cited in [1] which is more math oriented:

S. Khot, [Inapproximability of NP-complete Problems, Discrete Fourier Analysis, and Geometry](http://cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/icm-khot.pdf), ICM 2010.

---

[1] S. Khot, [On the Unique Games Conjecture](http://cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/UGCSurvey.pdf), CCC 2010.